# Assigning shortcut to Action tools in a Macro set

Tags: macros, keyboard-shortcuts, imagej

I'm writing a Macro set, with several Action tools. Is there a possibility of assigning shortcuts to my action tools?

I tried it like I would do it with a normal macro:

```
macro "Sample [f5]" {}
```

But it isn't working, no matter where I put the square brackets... :

```
macro "Sample Action Tool - C0a0L18f8L818f " { }
```

Could anyone please help me? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ImageJ user guide](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-35.html) has an answer:

> Keyboard shortcuts **cannot be used** directly to activate tools in the ImageJ Toolbar (with the exception of the Magnifying Glass and the Scrolling Tool). However, shortcuts can be assigned to macros that use the setTool() macro function.

So you might want to add a macro in addition to your macro tool:

```js
macro "Sample [f5]" {setTool(15)}
```

where you have to adjust `15` (which will activate the first custom tool) to the position of your tool.